# EditText height-length

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, notepad

I have been trying to create a simple note pad and I can't create in xml file an `EditText` that would match parent like that:

[image: notepad]

in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</TableLayout>
```

I want full screen to be match parent with the editText.

not like this...... I want text that it would be entered in left align

[image: picc]

please help!!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the gravity :
**Using** the following `code`

```
  <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.62" >

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editText1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:ems="10"
          android:gravity="left"
          android:inputType="textPersonName" >
          <requestFocus />
      </EditText>  
        </RelativeLayout>
```

***Screenshot:***

[image: Screenshot]:

Answer (score 1):

Change your `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` into `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

**Update**
According to your updating image, it is because you set the parent layout (table layout) height to match with the screen. Set it back to wrap content and then you will have what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</TableLayout>
```

And here is the result

[image]

Comment: well i want an edittext that is like the first image.The second inserts the text in the center...sorry for my poor english i hope you understand me

Comment: Have you checked the code that I posted in the update? The `TableLayout` has the `layout_height` is `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Comment: not sure what you mean about "center". My above code gives the text left align. Check out my screenshot

Comment: @noobProgrammer might as well put your previous comment as an answer. It's the correct solution for me too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your edit text layout width as FILL_PARENT or MATCH_PARENT.